# Select an option element only when Angular retrieves the data from a resource object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-resource

I am trying to load a list of objects in a select html element. The problem is that the code is being compiled before the data is actually returned from the server. Thus, the option that I want to be selected in the select element is not being selected. How can I fix this?

I have the following HTML:

```
<select ng-options="location.name for location in locations" ng-model="selectedOption" />
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.locations = data.locations.getAll();
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.locations[1];
```

The data service makes a call to a RESTful service:

```
app.factory('data', function($resource) {
    var locationsResource = $resource('http://localhost:10128/api/locations/:id', {id: '@id'});

    return {
        locations: {
            getAll: function() {
                return locationsResource.query();
            }
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$promise` of your `$resource`, like this:

```
$scope.locations = data.locations.getAll();
$scope.locations.$promise.then(function (result) {
    $scope.selectedOption = result[1];
});
```

You can also add an error handling function after `.then()`.

Here's a great exemplification of how [promises in AngularJS](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) work.